# Sklearn Custom Imputer from prediction

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I asked this question on Stackoverflow, but thought it might be a better fit here.

I'm playing around with the titanic dataset, and wanted to create a custom imputer to fill in missing `age` values with predictions from a LinearRegression model.  Please find the code below:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin


titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')


class AgeImputer(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        self.model = LinearRegression()

        # just use two columns for this example
        self.independent_columns = ['fare', 'pclass']

        # split the null age values from rest of data
        self.null_age_data = x[pd.isnull(x['age'])]
        self.age_data = x[pd.isnull(x['age'])==False]

        # fit the model on age_data
        self.model.fit(self.age_data[self.independent_columns], self.age_data['age'])

        return self

    def transform(self, x):
        """ make predictions and return the whole dataframe """
        self.null_age_data['age'] = self.model.predict(self.null_age_data[self.independent_columns])

        return self.null_age_data.append(self.age_data)

age_imputer = make_pipeline(
    AgeImputer()
)

age_imputer.fit_transform(titanic)
```

The code does the following:

1. during the `fit` phase, it saves the entire dataframe as a variable (after splitting it on whether or not the `age` column is null or not)
2. Fits a linear regression model on the dataset where `age` is not null
3. During the transform phase, it predicts the null values.
4. Finally, concatenates the two dataframe and output the result.

I'm wondering if this is the best way to create an imputer like this.  The reason being, passing in the whole dataframe and saving it as a class variables feels like a waste of memory.  Is there a simpler solution than this where the memory usage might be more efficient?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add a short explanation for how you code works, and why you made any unorthodox choices if you did?

Comment: @K00lman I did my best to add some explanation.  Please check the edit, thanks!